# Вернуть массив к исходному виду VUE JS

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Есть переменная, содержащая в себе массив объектов. При клике на `checkbox`, объекты сортируются в зависимости от первой буквы в значении одного из ключей. То есть, сортируются по алфавиту.

**НО.** Как сделать так, чтобы при повторном клике (когда чекбокс принимает `false`), массив объектов приходил к исходному виду?

```js
new Vue({
      el: '.townsProject',
      data: {

        towns: [{
            town: Moscow,
            yearvisited: 2015
          },
          {
            town: Saint - Petersburg,
            yearvisited: 2019
          },
          {
            town: Novorossiisk,
            yearvisited: 2016
          }
        ]
      },
      methods: sort: function() {
        this.towns.sort(function(a, b) {
          if (a.town > b.town) {
            return 1;
          }
          if (a.town < b.town) {
            return -1;
          }
          return 0;
        })
      }
```

```html
<div class="townsProject">
  <input class="container__movieList__seen" type='checkbox' id='sort2' v-on:click="sort()">
  <label for='sort2'>Отсортировать по алфавиту</label>
</div>
```

Comment: Массив фильтруется или сортируется? В тексте - фильтруется, в коде - сортируется. Где правда?

Comment: Добавить в towns свойство для сохранения порядка (на пример orderIdx), заполнять его при инициализации порядковым номером элемента в массиве и использовать как сортировку по-умолчанию.

Comment: @stepanKasyanenko сортируется, прошу прощения) исправила

Answer (score 0):

Не нужно изменять исходный массив. Для этого лучше использовать `computed` свойство. И не забудьте клонировать исходный массив прежде чем сортировать, например, с помощью `[].concat()`

```js
new Vue({
  el: '.townsProject',
  data() {
    return {
      sort: false,
      towns: [
        {
          town: "Moscow",
          yearvisited: 2015
        },
        {
          town: "Saint - Petersburg",
          yearvisited: 2019
        },
        {
          town: "Novorossiisk",
          yearvisited: 2016
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  computed: {
    sorted_list() {
      if (this.sort) {
        return [].concat(this.towns).sort(function(a, b) {
          if (a.town > b.town) {
            return 1;
          }
          if (a.town < b.town) {
            return -1;
          }
          return 0;
        })
      }
      return this.towns
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div class="townsProject">
  <input class="container__movieList__seen" type='checkbox' id='sort2' v-model="sort">
  <label for='sort2'>Отсортировать по алфавиту</label>
  <ul>
    <li v-for="town in sorted_list" :key="town.town">{{ town.town }}</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

---

PS: Всегда инициализируйте объект `data` c помощью функции:

```
data() {
    return {
        ...
    }
}
```

иначе, если компонент будет использоваться несколько раз на странице, они будут ссылаться на один объект и доставят много неприятностей. В варианте с функцией - при инициализации компонента будет создан обособленный объект

Comment: Не подскажете почему нельзя изменять исходный массив?

Comment: Причина в вопросе. Чтобы сохранить исходные данные)

Answer (score -1):

Вам необходимо сохранять изначальный порядок элементов. Для этого можно добавить свойство к объектам массива `towns`, к примеру `orderIndex`. При клике Вы можете передавать в метод событие и определять отмечен ли чекбокс или нет. Если "да", то можно брать значение value из чекбокса и использовать его для сортировки, если "нет", то использовать значение по-умолчанию. Выглядеть это может примерно так:

```html
<input type='checkbox' value="town" v-on:click="sort($event)" />
```

```js
new Vue({
  el: '.townsProject',
  data: {
    towns: [
      { town: "Moscow", orderIndex: 0},
      { town: "Saint-Petersburg", orderIndex: 1 },
      { town: "Novorossiisk", orderIndex: 2}
    ]
  },
  methods: {
    sort: function (ev) {
      var isChecked = ev.target.checked;
      var sortProp = isChecked ? ev.target.value : 'orderIndex';
      this.towns.sort(function (a, b) {
        if (a[sortProp] > b[sortProp]) {
          return 1;
        }
        if (a[sortProp] < b[sortProp]) {
          return -1;
        }
        return 0;
      });
    }
  }
});
```

По этому принципу можно построить сортировку по другим свойствам, но это будет удобней сделать с радио-кнопками, т.к. отмечен будет лишь один элемент, в отличии от чекбоксов, где пользователь может создать любую комбинацию из отмеченных и не отмеченных элементов.

Comment: Хоть бы указали за что минус... В чём ошибка? Предложенный вариант не решает проблему? Не по фэн-шую? Луна не в той фазе?